# Why cannot the sandwich SE be used when the Kenward-Roger denominator df are in use?

Tags: r, mixed-model, sas, degrees-of-freedom, sandwich

This question is about mixed models, and the use of both the Kenward-Roger correction (K-R) for small sample sizes and robust (sandwich) estimators for standard errors in the same model. Is it theoretically possible to estimate a mixed model with both K-R and robust (sandwich) standard error corrections?

Comment: Welcome to the site. It's not clear if your question is about SAS and R (which would be off topic) or mixed models (which would be on topic). I have a feeling it is the latter, but you should clarify by editing your question.

Comment: @PeterFlom-ReinstateMonica  I changed the wording, no reference to any package. So how do I unblock the topic now? Should I repost it? I need the answer urgently, but now nobody can even see this.

Comment: On the contrary, editing your post puts it into a review queue that brings it to everybody's attention. But please don't expect lots of people to look at it on a weekend!  For more information about getting attention to a question, please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers and https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: It's now re-opened. This isn't always a place for rapid responses - sometimes it is and sometimes it isn't.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve by using both K-R and robust SEs? Perhaps we can help to identify a different solution? Can you please update your initial post with this information and/or briefly state it as a comment? Edit:  I can tell you that in Stata, it is not possible using the mixed routine to get both in the same model.